# How to troubleshooting Construction Injection using Ninject

Tags: ninject.web.mvc

I am having problem with construction injection fail.

When I call Restful API, the service return the message "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'TasksController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor."

The cause of this issue is the Web API Controller can't construct the class because of wrong parameter in the constructor.

This is Ninject Configuration

```
container.Bind<IAddTaskQueryProcessor>().To<AddTaskQueryProcessor>().InRequestScope();
container.Bind<ITaskByIdQueryProcessor>().To<TaskByIdQueryProcessor>().InRequestScope();
container.Bind<IPagedDataRequestFactory>().To<PagedDataRequestFactory>().InSingletonScope();
container.Bind<IAllTasksInquiryProcessor>().To<AllTasksInquiryProcessor>().InRequestScope();
```

This is a constructor of a class of a Controller. the parameters are injected when calling the constructor.

```
public TasksController(IAddTaskMaintenanceProcessor addTaskMaintenanceProcessor, ITaskByIdInquiryProcessor taskByIdInquiryProcessor,
        IUpdateTaskMaintenanceProcessor updateTaskMaintenanceProcessor, 
        IPagedDataRequestFactory pagedDataRequestFactory,
        IAllTasksInquiryProcessor allTasksInquiryProcessor)
    {
        _addTaskMaintenanceProcessor = addTaskMaintenanceProcessor;
        _taskByIdInquiryProcessor = taskByIdInquiryProcessor;
        _updateTaskMaintenanceProcessor = updateTaskMaintenanceProcessor;
        _pagedDataRequestFactory = pagedDataRequestFactory;
        _allTasksInquiryProcessor = allTasksInquiryProcessor;
    }
```

[Environment]
ASP.NET Web API 2.1
NInject 3.2.2

How to check which parameter in a constructor is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. the parameters in the constructor are injected correctly. but a parameter IAllTaskQueryProcess in AllTaskInqueryProcess's constructor is not injected. so that ASP.NET engine can't invoke the controller class

```
public AllTasksInquiryProcessor(IAllTasksQueryProcessor queryProcessor, IAutoMapper autoMapper)
    {
        _queryProcessor = queryProcessor;
        _autoMapper = autoMapper;
    }
```